# Gatling - extract data from JSON array response

Tags: arrays, json, gatling, jsonpath

If I have a response of this kind:

```
{
  "A": 2,
  "B": [
    {
      "CCC": "abcde",
      "DDD": {
        "EEE": 11,
        "FFF": 22
      }
    },
    {
      "CCC": "fghij",
      "DDD": {
        "EEE": 111,
        "FFF": 222
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

how can I get **all** the values CCC in a list or otherwise?

If I use:

```
.check(jsonPath("$..CCC").saveAs("VARIABLE"))
```

I only get the first CCC ("abcde"). Doing it via CCC[*] throws an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, you should have to add findAll in check statement.

for example:

```
.check(jsonPath("$..[*].CCC").findAll.saveAs("VARIABLE"))
```

And please define your error.

Cheers,
Peekay

Comment: Hi, Peekay. This has worked, I guess. I get this result (for 5 values):

Some(Vector(8a7d477d-59a0-4920-ad10-8c1a7fd65c3b, af9efa88-a358-40b1-b206-c90555b6ff52, ba22986e-1b92-4dbf-b95f-1ed8b428d9e4, 47b96be4-4e5c-4afa-baa9-a4a118606c84, 63abc057-8f0e-48ca-881d-c2308b1e4811))
The 5 values are IDs of a sort.
I believe this is a Sequence? How do you iterate and work with sequences...?

Comment: Hi Alichino,

First, findAll collects all values. No matter how many values are there.
And second, You can follow, "${abc(0)}, ${abc(1)}, ${abc(2)}, ..." to pass the values sequentially.
I think, You have found your answer.

Cheers, 
Peekay