# Gatling: How to extract one object from array?

Tags: arrays, object, gatling, jsonpath, scala-gatling

I am new in Gatling and Scala. Sending Get Request the response body is Array and I need to extract only one object from Array and post it in Gatling. Can someone explain to me how to do it?

Here is my code example:

```
private val getUsers = exec(
      http("Get users")
        .get("/users")
        .check(status.is(200))
        .check(bodyString.saveAs("Users")))
```

The result that I get is:

```
[{"id":"1","hairColor":"BROWN","age":24,"language":"English","birthDate":"1995-02-10"},
{"id":"2","hairColor":"YELLOW","age":30,"language":"Australian","birthDate":"1889-10-05"},
{"id":"3","hairColor":"BLACK","age":15,"language":"American","birthDate":"..."},
{"id":"4","hairColor":"RED","age":50,"language":"Russian","birthDate":"..."}]
```

How to get whatever only one User from this array and post entire User object?

Comment: Have you tried this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277962/gatling-extract-data-from-json-array-response

Comment: @jPO yes, I was looking at this example but it didn't help me to solve mine problem. My example is different.

Comment: when you say 'one user', do you want just the id, or do you need to submit the entire json object for a user?

Comment: @JamesWarr I would like to submit the entire json object for user

Comment: I don't believe American and Australian are languages. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you switch to a jsonPath check, you can get all the user objects into a Vector which has some nice support in the Gatling EL

so instead of

```
.check(bodyString.saveAs("Users"))
```

you can use

```
.check(jsonPath("$..[?(@.id)]").findAll.saveAs("Users")))
```

then when you come to make your subsequent calls, you can do things like

select the 1st user with

```
.body(StringBody("${Body(1).jsonStringify()}"))
```

select a random user with

```
.body(StringBody("${Body.random().jsonStringify()}"))
```

This approach will also allow you to use `.forEach` to interate over all the records

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer by myself. If I want to save whatever one object from array I can do this ->

```
private val getUsers = exec(
  http("Get users")
    .get("/users")
    .check(status.is(200))
    .check(jsonPath("$[0]").find.saveAs("user")))
```

Of course, I have to specify which value I want to save but in my example, I am saving the first value. And later you can use this value for other requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can easy get, but you need define which key

Its example where I used 'id' by the key

`$.[*].[?(@.id == '1')]`

---

`$.[*]` <= get all elem of array

`.[?(@.id == '1')]`  <= get element which id equals to '1' (you can use any value).

Or any key `$.[*].[?(@.hairColor == 'BROWN')]`

---

Then just add
`.check(jsonPath("$.[*].[?(@.id == '1')]").saveAs("myUser")`